# Error while creating rails new app project

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Can't overcome problem. Everytime i generating new rails project on windows get the massage:

```
Installing json (1.6.5) with native extensions
Gem::Installer::ExtensionBuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

   C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe: No such file or directory -- extconf.rb (LoadError)

Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.5 
for inspection.
Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/json-1.6.5/ext/json/ext/parser/gem_make.out
An error occured while installing json (1.6.5), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install json -v '1.6.5'` succeeds before bundling.
```

i've tried instal json but without lack... I've manage to instal json_pure. But still get this error. 'ruby dk.rb init' not worked too

Comment: Windows isn't really good way for Ruby on Rails development. I recommend you to switch to Unix system, for example, Ubuntu.

Comment: +1 ExR  You could be up and running in an hour or two with a dual-boot.  Best of both worlds.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For building native extensions on Windows, you need to install [DevKit](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/development-kit).  It gives you a Unix-like environment and compilers.

Comment: have tried this with rubyinstaller already (it comes with devkit)...same result

Comment: 'not working'? What's the error?  Have you added the devkit 'bin' and 'mingw\bin' to your path?